# How do I get started with Mobile Responsive Website Development

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

As I'm a new web developer with initial knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript; how do I get started to design a responsive website both for desktop and mobile?

Please suggest me documents/tutorials/guides etc. or frameworks which are helpful for development of mobile responsive websites.

Comment: use bootstrap its makes your website responsive for both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap

> Bootstrap is the most popular and powerful front-end (HTML, CSS, and JS) framework for faster and easier responsive web development.

Website: [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Reference: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

Reference: [tutorialrepublic.com](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-responsive-layout.php)

Reference: [sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-responsive-websites-using-twitter-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a php framework, then I suggest you to go for laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2). It has built in bootstrap classes for a responsive web design.
It is OOP framework which has a artisan command line that helps you create migrations to your database and there is eloquent ORM, so you can use any database which also prevents sql injections. Also it is based on the symphony. It has predefined authentication and you can define your urls within the routes with authentication. Composer, standard autoloading, namespacing, dependency injection allow us to mix and match packages with no hassle. Laravel can make good use of powerful and tested third party libraries without having to reinvent the wheel and rewriting something which already exists. There are many services provided.

Last but not the least, the documentation has almost everything but still if you find difficulty then there are these awesome tutorials at laracasts. [laracasts- Its kinda like Netflix for developers](https://laracasts.com/).